# Solid Geometry (Simple) Problem. How do I compute the radius of a circle generated by an intersection between an ellipsoid and a plane?

Tags: geometry

I'm getting crazy. I'm not a mathematician but I need such an answer to implement a functionality in my project.
More precisely my question is the following. I have an ellipsoid (a spheroid actually) of which I know the measure of the axis. Now, a plane intersects the spheroid perpendicularly to on axis (the different one from the other two). On the top of the spheroid I now hav a circle, with a radius. I know at which height the plane has intersected the spheroid, it is possible to compute the radius of this circle, depending on the height at which it intersect the spheroid?

Comment: I added an interactive GeoGebra worksheet. Have fun.

Answer (score 2):

Certainly. If the spheroid isn’t in standard position—centered on the origin and the $z$-axis as the odd-length axis, then translate and rotate so that it is. The equation of the plane will now be of the form $z=k$. Substituting this into the transformed spheroid equation $${x^2+y^2\over a^2}+{z^2\over b^2}=1$$ gives you the equation of a circle, which you can rearrange into the standard-looking $$x^2+y^2 = a^2\left(1-{k^2\over b^2}\right).$$ The quantity on the right-hand side is the square of the circle’s radius.

There are other ways to compute this, but they also effectively involve transforming the spheroid into a more convenient form.

Answer (score 1):

**Model of the spheroid:**

Assume the points on the spheroid are described by
$$
(x/a)^2 + (y/a)^2 + (z/c)^2 = 1
$$
which means the center is at the origin and the spheroid has the axes $a$ and $c$.

**Model of the plane:**

The plane can be modeled as
$$
d
= n \cdot u
= (0,0,1) \cdot (x, y, z) 
= 0\cdot x + 0 \cdot y + 1 \cdot z
= z
$$
which is a plane with unit normal vector $n$ and distance $d$ from the origin.

**The intersection curve:**

Then the intersection consists of all points fulfilling both equations.

So we have
$$
(x/a)^2 + (y/a)^2 + (d/c)^2 = 1 \\
z = d
$$
This can be rearranged into
$$
x^2 + y^2 = a^2 \left( 1 - (d/c)^2 \right) = r^2 \\
z = d
$$
which are the equations of a circle in the $x$, $y$ plane at height $d$ with radius
$$
r = a \sqrt{1 - \left(\frac{d}{c}\right)^2}
$$
if $d < c$.

**Update:**

[image]

You can fiddle with the model [here](https://www.geogebra.org/classic/yxsuez3y).